# Excel doesn't create array formulas

Tags: excel

Yesterday I have succesfully created an array formula: =IFERROR(FIND("Made";$E5:$E3000);"")
Today I copied the formula into a new file and it also works.
If I copy the formula inside the new file, it doesn't fork. Also doesn't work when I write it again.
It creates the brackets around it but the formula is only in the first cell.

I am using Excel 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: Provide English names of functions. I guess, not many people know what `NAJÍT` means.

Comment: Excel 2016 does **not** spill results

Comment: I use Czech functions and don't know English names the same way you don't know Czech. I think it's FIND? But it's not about this specific function, no functions work in that sheet.

Comment: I don't understand what jvdv means.

Answer (score 0):

if you type Curly Bracket, Formula won't work

Type Formula without Bracket and Press Ctrl + Shift + Enter

```
Ctrl + Shift + Enter
```

Then the formula will become matrix formula.

Comment: it won't, which my post is about

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by copying the formula from the original sheet. Would be interesting to find why it works sometimes and sometimes not enough.
I hope nobody else will have this problem but I find many problems work array formulas here.